# VScode on OSX - GIT ssh key passphrase - working from build in terminal put not from command palette

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, ssh, passphrase

I can connect to the Git server and do anything I want from the VSCode build in terminal, but, as soon as I use the command pallette and want to perform a push, it fails as now passphrase prompt is shown.

Is there any way to avoid entering the passphrase at each push?

Answer (score 3):

That seems expected considering the [Remote Development Tips and Tricks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_enabling-alternate-ssh-authentication-methods) section:

> ### Enabling alternate SSH authentication methods#
>
> If you are connecting to an SSH remote host and are either:
>
> - Connecting with two-factor authentication
> - Using password authentication
> - Using an SSH key with a passphrase when the SSH Agent is not running or accessible
>
> then VS Code should automatically prompt you to enter needed information. I

So make sure the [SSH agent is running locally](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent)

> VS Code will automatically add your key to the agent so you don't have to enter your passphrase every time you open a remote VS Code window.
>
> To verify that the agent is running and is reachable from VS Code's environment, run `ssh-add -l` in the terminal of a local VS Code window.
> You should see a listing of the keys in the agent (or a message that it has no keys).
> If the agent is not running, follow these instructions to start it. After starting the agent, be sure to restart VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

[Automatically load keys into the ssh-agent and store passphrases in the keychain](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent): (see step 2)

If you're using macOS Sierra 10.12.2 or later, you will need to modify your ~/.ssh/config file to automatically load keys into the ssh-agent and store passphrases in your keychain.

First, check to see if your ~/.ssh/config file exists in the default location.

```
$ open ~/.ssh/config
> The file /Users/YOU/.ssh/config does not exist.
```

If the file doesn't exist, create the file.

```
$ touch ~/.ssh/config
```

Open your ~/.ssh/config file, then modify the file to contain the following lines. If your SSH key file has a different name or path than the example code, modify the filename or path to match your current setup.

```
Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score -1):

to make it work I had to ad the key to OSX keychain and configure it in .ssh/config

Comment: How? Where? This is not an anwser.